# Is $(J_{\lambda_n})_n$ convergent in $\mathcal L(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Let $I:H \to H$ be the identity map. For every $\lambda>0$, set
$$
J_\lambda=(I+\lambda A)^{-1} \quad \text { and } \quad A_\lambda=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(I-J_\lambda\right) ;
$$
$J_\lambda$ is called the *resolvent* of $A$, and $A_\lambda$ is the *Yosida approximation* (or *regularization*) of $A$. Then we [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740165/is-it-true-that-j-lambda-n-j-lambda-mathcal-lh-to-0-as-lambd)

1. $\left\|J_\lambda\right\|_{\mathcal{L}(H)} \leq 1$ for $\lambda>0$.
2. $\lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} J_\lambda v = v$ for all $v \in H$.
3. If $\lambda_n, \lambda >0$ such that $\lambda_n \to \lambda$, then $\|J_{\lambda_n} - J_\lambda\|_{\mathcal L(H)} \to 0$.

On the space $\mathcal L(H)$, we have [strong operator topology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Strong_operator_topology) (SOT), [norm operator topology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Operator_norm) (NOT), and [weak operator topology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weak_operator_topology) (WOT). We have SOT is stronger than WOT and weaker than NOT.

Now let $\lambda_n >0$ such that $\lambda_n \to 0$.

> Does $(J_{\lambda_n})_n$ converge in any of those topologies of $\mathcal L(H)$ as $n \to \infty$? If yes, what is its limit?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday?

Comment: @FShrike Yesterday's question dealt with convergence when $\lambda_n \to \lambda > 0$, and here the question is with $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The convergence in SOT is equivalent to the pointwise convergence which has been already proved
- The convergence in WOT will be a consequence of the convergence in SOT.
- However, the convergence in NOT is not true in general. Take $H=L^2([0,1], \mathbb C)$, $A= -i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$ and $v_n = e^{i2n\pi x}$ then

$$Av_n = 2n\pi v_n$$ $$J_{\frac1n}v_n = \frac1{1+2\pi} v_n$$

$$\left\|J_{\frac1n} - I\right\|_{\mathcal L(H)}\ge \left\| J_{\frac1n}v_n - v_n\right\|= \frac{2\pi}{1+2\pi}$$

Comment: I have updated my thread to weaken the topology on $\mathcal L(H)$. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: Yes let me update my answer.

Comment: I update my answer with some details.

Comment: Great! I'm not familiar with complex analysis. Do you have a counter-example with real-valued functions?

Comment: I can think about it. But you can consider $A=\frac d{dx}$ and $v_n = \sin(2n\pi x)$